# check process every 30sec in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Hi iuse this code for check Process after my App "piko.exe" run and if the programs such as 
"non.exe","firefox.exe","lol.exe" if running closed my App and return an error.

But i need to this check process every 30 sec and i used while but my main program (this code is one part of my project) stopped working so pleas if possible pls someone edited my code thank you.

```
#include "StdInc.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void find_Proc(){



HANDLE proc_Snap;
HANDLE proc_pik;
HANDLE proc_pikterm;

PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32pik;

int i;
char* chos[3] = {"non.exe","firefox.exe","lol.exe"};

char* piko = "piko.exe";

proc_pik = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
proc_Snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );

pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
pe32pik.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);


for(i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){

    Process32First(proc_Snap , &pe32);
    do{

        if(!strcmp(chos[i],pe32.szExeFile)){
            MessageBox(NULL,"CHEAT DETECTED","ERROR",NULL);
            Process32First(proc_pik,&pe32pik);
                do{

                    if(!strcmp(iw4m,pe32pik.szExeFile)){

                        proc_pikterm =  OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, pe32pik.th32ProcessID);

                        if(proc_pikterm != NULL)
                            TerminateProcess(proc_pikterm, 0);
                        CloseHandle(proc_pikterm);
                    }

                } while(Process32Next(proc_pik, &pe32pik));

    }

} while(Process32Next(proc_Snap, &pe32));
}
CloseHandle(proc_Snap);

CloseHandle(proc_pik);
}
```

Comment: BTW you should exchange the order of the loops.  And you should not need a second snapshot to find your process.  And if the user never clicks "OK" on the "Cheat Detected" message, your program will never call `TerminateProcess`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what OS you're using you can poll the system time and check to see if 30 seconds have expired.  The way to do so is to take the time at the beginning of your loop, take the time at the end and subtract them.  Then subtract the time you want to sleep from the time it took your code to run that routine.

Also, if you don't need EXACTLY 30 seconds, you could just add sleep(30) to your loop.

Comment: Sleep takes milliseconds on windows. So 30 seconds are Sleep(30000)

Comment: look i used
`
    while(true){

    ...

    }

    sleep(30) 
`
but my main app stopped working so i need other method?!

Comment: @artines: What else does your app do?  Does it have a UI?  Try using `SetTimer` to have a `WM_TIMER` sent every 30 seconds, and do the checks when you see it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain to me why this method wouldn't work for you?  The code below is designed to count up one value each second.  Make "checkMyProcess" do whatever you need it to do within that while loop before the sleep call.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int someGlobal = 5;//Added in a global so you can see what fork does, with respect to not sharing memory!

bool checkMyProcess(const int MAX) {
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < MAX) {
        cout << "CHECKING: " << counter++ <<  " Global: " << someGlobal++ << endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void doOtherWork(const int MIN) {
    int counter = 100;
    while(counter > MIN) {
        cout << "OTHER WORK:" << counter-- << " Global: " << someGlobal << endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0) {
        checkMyProcess(5);
    } else {
        doOtherWork(90);
    }
}
```

Realize of course that, if you want to do work outside of the while loop, within this same program, you would have to use threading, or fork a pair of processes.

EDIT:

I added in a call to "fork" so you can see the two processes doing work at the same time.  Note: if the "checkMyProcess" function needs to know something about the memory going on in the "doOtherWork" function threading will be a much easier solution for you!